# What convention starts text scripts with '# -*- mode: python; -*-'?

Tags: python, text-editors

I encountered some python scripts in the wild with this first line:

```
# -*- mode: python; -*-
```

I can infer that it's some indicator to some system that it should operate on the file as python, and I am further assuming that it's an indicator to a text editor to highlight the file a certain way.  I would like to use it for that purpose if possible (i.e., if I haven't completely mis-guessed what it's purpose is).

What I don't know is what editor supports it, or even the name of the convention so that I could seek out a plugin to support it in my editor.  And as text, this line really doesn't play nicely with google searching.

What is that convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an Emacs-style mode line, written as a python comment.
The generic form is `-*- mode: modename; var: value; … -*-`

The Emacs manual includes all the details: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html